# Does NSUrlSession Prevent the Application from suspending?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, nsurlsession

I have an app that send 300+ files across the network, normally we request an additional 10 minutes timer when the app moves to the background in case we need to send, but after 10 minutes the app is moved to the suspended state.

Can NSUrlConnection prevent this suspension and continue download from the background>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you get only 3 minutes in iOS 7, not 10 as before.
2. `NSURLConnection` cannot help you there.
3. `NSURLSession` has a facility for uploading files in the background, outside of that time. However, it doesn't keep a continuous task running like `UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier`-based methods, and you *must* use on-device files as the basis of the upload. I found it to take a lot of work to get it right, so be prepared. I'd start with a thorough review of Apple's [URL Loading System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165-BCICJDHA), which isn't really well written, but is entirely necessary.